# searching multiple strings in a single file

Tags: unix, command-line, grep

I want to find the lines in which atleast one of the strings among string1 and string2 are present in the file.

`grep 'string1' 'string2' file`;-this  is an error even though!!

how could i do the above on unix command line?

Answer (score 1):

If your version of grep supports the `-E` flag (e.g. the GNU version), you can use extended regular expressions, which allows you to perform queries like this:

```
$ grep -E 'string1|string2'
```

or

```
$ grep -E 'string[12]'
```

See pcresyntax(3) and pcrepattern(3) for further information on PCRE (Perl Compatible Regular Expressions).

Answer (score -1):

Found it!!

```
grep -e 'string1' -e 'string2' file;
```